# Как проверить защищенность веб-сервера?

Tags: безопасность, веб-сервер

Какими средствами (программами, скриптами, сервисами и т.д.) можно проверить реальную степень защищенности веб-сервера? Есть ли что-либо вроде промышленного стандарта для подобных задач?

Answer (score 1):

Часто используют разнообразные сканеры (например, [Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/products/nessus)), которые отслеживают различные виды уязвимостей. Вдобавок к этому у Microsoft есть свой [анализатор](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/security/cc184923).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду, что-то типа сканера безопасности, то таковых много, но ни один не даёт гарантию. Лучший способ это установка сигнализаторов о вторжениях на самом сервере, думаю, что на любом веб-сервере хорошо бы иметь следующие:

- Установите и настройте: **rkhunter**, **chkrootkit**. Это утилиты для обнаружения руткитов.
- Отслеживайте подозрительные записи логов с помощью **logwatch** и **logcheck**
- Посмотрите в сторону [Snort](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort) (система предотвращения вторжений)

Если все-таки нужно клиент-серверное приложение, то взгляните на [OSSEC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSSEC)